# How to stop Zend Framework from appending '/scripts/' to the View Base Path

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

Thats basically my code (simplified):

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->view->setBasePath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/partner/xyz/');
        $this->view->render('node.phtml');
    }
}
```

Now what I (obvoiusly) want is to use the view script `APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/partner/xyz/node.phtml'` but ZF always tries to load `APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/partner/xyz/scripts/node.phtml'` is there any Way around that Behviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the path to the view tih the setScriptPath method.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/partner/xyz');
        //$this->view->setBasePath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/partner/xyz/');
        $this->view->render('node.phtml');
    }
}
```

Comment: omg ... thaaanks ... sometimes I can't believe how blind I am xD now I remember that I already had that issue some months ago and solved it and then completely forgot about it - apparently

Answer (score 0):

I need to change the script path, not just view path:
`public function setScriptPath($path);`